# AWS Cognito multi level multi tenancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

i've got a question for some experts on AWS Cognito. We have the following requirement:

**SaaS Service (Multi-Tenancy)**

- Customer A
- - Role A / Group A
- - - User1
- Customer B
- - Role A / Group A
- - - User1

so far so easy, but we also need the customers to be able to have multi tenancy within their tenant:

**SaaS Service**

- Customer A
- - Client 1
- - - Role A / Group A
- - - - User1
- - Client 2
- - - Role A / Group A
- - - - User1
- Customer B
- - Client 1
- - - Role A / Group A
- - - - User1

Customers must be able to create roles within each **client**. They also need to create users per **client** and assign them roles.

Users should be created on **client** level but it would also be possible to create them on **customer** level and "somehow" grant access to specific **clients**. But they need to have different permission levels on each **client**.

We also are unsure of how we would create "application"-level permissions which each customer could then assign to their roles. The roles of each customer must only be able to contain the **application**-level roles not any of the AWS **service**-level permissions.

There would be a need for a lambda trigger which would add the "tenant_id" and "client_id" to the jwt so each service can use this information to restrict access to their data.

Is this even something one could consider using Cogito for? How would you assign / map the Identity Pools. If anyone is able to share some insight on this it would be a tremandous help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you provisioning a user pool for each customer?

Comment: atm we are not planning to, but if that helps we could consider it